# Error when initialize rosdep

Tags: ros, rosdep, raspberrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using Raspberry Pi 3 (Raspbian Jessie PIXEL). I'm trying to install ROS based on this tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Kinetic%20on%20the%20Raspberry%20Pi.

The error I got is:

```
sudo rosdep init
ERROR: cannot download default sources list from: https://raw.github.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list
Website may be down.
```

I read a solution on this link http://answers.ros.org/question/54150/rosdep-initialization-error/, but I don't know what is the proxy server and host of my Raspberry, and I don't know how to find it too? (I'm quite new to both Raspberry and Linux, but I need to install ROS for my project).

And when I browse the link on the error, the website cannot be opened and it says "Your connection is not private".

Can anyone explain a little bit detailed how to find proxy server and port, and what to do next to fix this problem?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258216/error-when-initialize-rosdep/) by [thanhvu94](https://answers.ros.org/users/29865/thanhvu94/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2017-03-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,
I had been facing the same issue of
ERROR: cannot download default sources list from:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list
Website may be down.

This error is because of your system date & time settings. I corrected my systems date and time settings and rosdep init worked.

---

Originally posted by [Shoeb Ahmed](https://answers.ros.org/users/33157/shoeb-ahmed/) with karma: 41 on 2018-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2018-01-05**:
Yes, the https negotiations will fail if the date and time are too far apart.